# What is this space homeomorphic/homotopy equivalent to?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X \subset \mathbb{C}^2$ be given by the equation

$$|z|^2 + |w|^2=1$$ and let $A \subset X$ be given by $|z|=1,\ w=0$.

This question requires me to find the relative homology groups $H_n(X,A)$, but before I do that I would like to ask if my guess is correct.

Is $X$ homeomorphic/homotopy equivalent to $S^4$, and $A$ homeomorphic/homotopy equivalent to $S^2$?

Comment: The dimensions are one lower, $X \cong S^3$ and $A \cong S^1$.

Comment: Oh yes, I got confused. $S^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Thanks!

Comment: Just a further hint $H_n(X,A)=H_n(S^2)$.

Comment: Actually, is it true that $S^n$ quotient by $S^{n-2}, S^{n-1}$? I can't visualize it.

Comment: Oh wait, no matter what $n$ is, it should be $S^2$.

Comment: Well, things are not so. Answer is NO.