# The exact sequence of a pair - something fishy going on here!

Tags: algebraic-topology

This question is related to my [previous question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770065/what-is-this-space-homeomorphic-homotopy-equivalent-to)

After knowing that $X \cong S^3$ and $A \cong S^1$, with $X/A \cong S^2$, I attempt to construct the long exact sequence of a pair. I need to use the exact sequence of a pair to find the relative homology groups $H_n(X,A)$.

$... \rightarrow \tilde{H}_n(S^1)\rightarrow \tilde{H}_n(S^3) \rightarrow \tilde{H}_n(S^2)\rightarrow...\rightarrow \tilde{H}_3(S^1)\rightarrow\tilde{H}_3(S^3)\rightarrow\tilde{H}_3(S^2)\rightarrow\tilde{H}_2(S^1)\rightarrow...$

There seems to be something really fishy here. I know that $\tilde{H}_3(S^3) \cong\mathbb{Z}$, but $\tilde{H}_3(S^2)=0$! How can this be? Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Why do you think $S^3/S^1$ is homeomorphic to $S^2$?

Comment: Well I don't even know that... sigh

Comment: Consider a point $x\in S^3\setminus S^1$ and let $U\subset S^3\setminus S^1$ be a small open neighbourhood of $x$ homeomorphic to a $3$-ball. As $U$ doesn't intersect $S^1$, a homeomorphic copy must exist as a subset of the quotient $S^3/ S^1$. The sphere $S^2$ does not contain any subsets homeomorphic to a $3$-ball because it is a $2$-dimensional manifold/surface.

Comment: There is the Hopf fibration $S^1 \to S^3 \to S^2$, however.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such sequence with reduced homology $\widetilde H$. But there is a long exact sequence of homotopy groups $\pi$. And, indeed, $\pi_3(S^2)=\mathbb{Z}$. It sounds like you are confusing the long exact homology sequence of a pair of spaces $A \subset X$ with the long exact homotopy sequence of a fibration.